# CSS hover multiple areas with images on one area mouseover

Tags: css, html, image, dictionary

I am in the process of creating a map.. where there are multiple areas that change colour on the map using CSS hover when mouse'd over...

So far I have used the main div as position:relative with the main map image as a background of the div and absolutely positioned the links that hover. The hover transitions to the images I have used opacity from 0 to 1.

My problem is that I cant seem to link multiple  elements(the islands) to hover using the same CSS as the rest, when one of these linked  elements are moused over.

Any help will be super appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div id="main"> 
<img class="africa" src="./img/map/africa.png" height="50"/>
<img class="centralamerica" src="./img/map/centralamerica.png" height="50"/>
<img class="southamerica" src="./img/map/southamerica.png" height="50"/>
<img class="asiapacific" src="./img/map/asiapacific.png" height="50"/>

<a id="islandlink" href="#islandlink">
<img class="caribean" src="./img/map/caribean.png" height="50"/>
<img class="madagascar" src="./img/map/madagascar.png" height="50"/>
<img class="pacific" src="./img/map/pacific.png" height="50"/></a>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  background-image: url(../img/map/map.png);
}

#main{
background-image: url(../img/map/map.png);
background-size: 960px 560px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:960px;
height:560px;
position:relative;
}

#main img.africa {
top: 248px;
left: 405.59px;
height: 35.5%;
position: absolute;
width: 18%;
opacity:0;
}

#main img.southamerica {
top: 316px;
left: 240px;
height: 35%;
position: absolute;
width: 13.5%;
opacity:0;
}

#main img.centralamerica {
top: 256px;
left: 158px;
height: 12.7%;
position: absolute;
width: 10.8%;
opacity:0;
}

#main img.asiapacific {
top: 188px;
left: 584.5px;
height: 49%;
position: absolute;
opacity:0;
}

#main img.africa:hover {
top: 248px;
left: 405.59px;
height: 35.5%;
position: absolute;
width: 18%;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

#main img.southamerica:hover {
top: 316px;
left: 240px;
height: 35%;
position: absolute;
width: 13.5%;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

#main img.centralamerica:hover {
top: 256px;
left: 158px;
height: 12.7%;
position: absolute;
width: 10.8%;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

#main img.asiapacific:hover {
top: 188px;
left: 584.5px;
height: 49%;
position: absolute;
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

<!--Islands-->

#islandlink {
top: 316px;
left: 240px;
height: 35%;
position: relative;
width: 13.5%;
opacity:1;
}

#islandlink img.caribean {
top: 288px;
left: 251px;
height: 3.3%;
position: absolute;
opacity:0;
}

#islandlink img.madagascar {
top: 376px;
left: 548px;
height: 6.5%;
position: absolute;
opacity:0;
}

#islandlink img.pacific {
top: 346px;
left: 816px;
height: 5%;
position: absolute;
opacity:0;
}

#islandlink img:hover {
opacity:1;
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your CSS with that if you want all the island images to appear in the same time.

```
#islandlink:hover img {
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) Please mark this question solved by this answer then :)